# Reconsider implementing a "return to top" button for long pages

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

I feel that after scrolling down through a large number of posts, that there should be a simple "back to top" button at the bottom right of the screen (or somewhere).

Consider this - if you put together a REALLY long page for a client's website, would you not put a Return to top button on that page? I would.

I have, tying it to the scroll event when the page gets past a certain scroll position, and I think it is a fair request.

As for using the home button, the whole point is that you are using the mouse wheel to scroll down, and it is tedious to either drag the scroll bar or search for a keyboard solution. With long infinite scrolling pages becoming normal, it is equally normal to have a simple "return to top" button on the page. I know this has been mooted before, but I thought it might be suitable for re-consideration.

Comment: Whats so bad about the "Home" key? How lazy can you be that even tho your hands are **already on** the keyboard you find pressing a key tedious?

Comment: its about giving options - not everyone uses the keyboard for everything and please refrain from negative personal attacks such as calling me lazy. The mere fact that I took the time to craft a request which is a valid request, indicates that I am not lazy, but requesting a feature, which is the very definition of a "feature request". And in fact my hands are not on the keyboard when scrolling  - since the scroll wheel is on the mouse! Also I referenced other related posts indicating  I have actually read the related posts and still decided to post because IT IS A VALID FEATURE REQUEST!!!!!!!!

Comment: Nothing helps drive home a point more than an all-caps shout and a bunch of exclamation marks.

Comment: Fair point @Carpetsmoker, I apologise to the forum. I just find the singleminded-ness mindboggling. To deny a feature simply because there is another option which is on a different device to the one being operated and this  coming from programmers who are much better and moreknowledgable than myself and then to be called lazy by another forum member made me a little tetchy.

Comment: Feature requests need to have an actual usefulness to the site, the RTT function will not solve anything since in reality there's not a real problem to be solved.

Comment: i know it is a dup of that but a) it didn't answer my request for the same reasons as we have been arguing about here - just cos there is a home button does not diminish the viability of a RTT button, and b) it was created two years ago and i am only new here and wanted to reopne productive discussions about an accebility feature that enhances usability. and jusrt cos its not a problem for you does not mean that its not a problem for me. The fact that I raised the issue indicates it it a problem for me that i would like to have mediated

Comment: @Just Do It: You scroll your browser with both hands on your keyboard? (If you actually do use MouseKeys or some form of AT that requires keyboard input, I rest my case.)

Comment: I usually use the mouse, but I use my keyboard too, you know those little things called arrow keys. Also when I feel like thinking outside of the box, I use another little thing called macros, oh and don't forget those page up page down keys. @BoltClock

Comment: The problem with those pesky keyboard keys is that they are on the right side of the keyboard and if you use the mouse on the right side of the keyboard like 98.32% of people, it involves taking your hand off the mouse, your eyes off the screen and to the keyboard to find the correct key and then back to the mouse and screen. Poor workflow. And if a macro is useful to create an effect in-browser, then another navigation element could be used, say for example, a button that could be navigated to and viewed on the screen without removing hands from the primary source of navigation. Just saying!

Comment: You have to look at the keyboard to know where the keys are? Wow, that is shocking to me. I never look at the keyboard. I can find any key I want on a standard keyboard layout by muscle memory and feel alone. Maybe you need to get a new keyboard, one that doesn't suck?

Comment: dude - really? just cos I can't touch type and never use the "home" button even when I do type, does not mean that its not a valid point. I don't want to interact with my keyboard when I am scrolling. Its that simple. If I wanted to only use my keyboard then swell, have at it but my point is just because you do it one way does not mean that everyone does it that way. And I don't dump on other people for their choices.

Comment: I also dont use the control button on the right hand side of the keyboard, but I am not suggesting we remove it, but why do you think keyboard manufactuers still put one on both sides of the keyboard - so that people have the ability to choose which one they want to use. Try being a little more open minded and open to the idea that not everyone necessarily wants to use the dam "home" button or the page up / down buttons or the arrows or the scroll pad for that matter. Why is there such resistance to a simple concept of "gee wouldn't it be nice to have an added feature for those who want it?

Comment: There is a resistance to adding undesired junk to the page. What you see as a useful feature, others see as garbage taking up space on the screen, completely redundant with several other more normal and more useful methods of achieving the same goal.

Comment: point taken - but at the moment there are 24 Hot Network Questions on my screen that hold absolutely no interest for me. My point is that for me that is undesired junk, and yet I don't complain about it. The entire argument revolves around the abilty to use / not use / see / not see a little link or button that would be pretty unobtrusive. And now the argument against adding a functional button is that it is undesirable to the site. then lets add it as a preference that you can turn on / off. Dammit we are programmers that can modify pages to achieve different things for different people.

Comment: Maybe if it also auto-inserted a 'tl;dr' comment?

Comment: then don't read it

Comment: @CodyGray It is a bit "shocking" indeed but I guess we're the odd 1.68% of people :^)

Answer (score 5):

This is a valid feature request.

Note that downvotes here indicate that the feature is being disagreed with, not the validity of the post; at least, for the most part (in general that is).

A return to top button doesn't really seem to solve a problem in my opinion, so I do not agree with this feature.

In the past, I have thought that having a back to top option would be a good idea, so I made a custom one. It will bookmark where you have scrolled to, toggle the topbar if you are scrolled lower in the page, and navigate to a previous bookmark (for example, if you chose to go back to top and wanted to return to a previous placement).

I almost never use it. It is "nice to have" but it most certainly not "need to have" and it is rather easy to simply glide over to the scroll bar, grab it with the mouse, and slide it to the top.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I submit that if you and others have considered the use of it in the past and thought it useful enough to implement a custom button / bookmark then it is a feature that is useful. Even if you "almost never use it", that infers that you sometimes use it and therefore it is useful. I for one would use it and for those people who downvote they don't need to use it. Everyone is different and uses different features of the site. For example I don't use the "Hot Network questions" , but I don't expect that it should be removed just because I don't use it.

Comment: And just to put numbers to it to validate my request, I just looked at the size of hte page in the console, and the full page is 8309px high!!! There is no way that I  would implement a page like that and not have a RTT function. Just telling my clients that their users can use the "home" button is ludicrous. To return to the top of the page requires 10 or 11 full scroll wheel movements. It should be remembered that this site is for all users not just those who dictate the use of the home button.

Comment: Using your reasoning, then why implement the RTT function? this site is for all users and not just those who want a RTT function.

Comment: laffing - the difference is that if it is there then you have the option to choose it or not, but if it is absent then you do not have the option to use it at all. Seems very petty and small minded and obstructionist. Why include the next button in the pagination options - when clearly there is a button that  will allow you to go to the next page or previous page by clicking the number buttons. Different people use different methods and we should be accepted for who we are and what we can offer the forum than bickering over something so patently stupid.

Comment: a constructive answer to my post might have been to select fewer posts in the page. I just noticed there is an option to select 15,30, or 50 posts per page, so it might have been more productive for a more experienced SO user to suggest that. I have obviously missed that option, but it would resolve my issue of long pages and allow me to click the next button to load the next page in. I am new to this forum and love it, but feel that this has not been a positive discussion of best policy practise. I would never create a page this long without an RTT, but now i have a viable alternative.

Answer (score -5):

Thank you to all who considered my request. Realising that this tradition of limiting the site navigation to the use of an unrelated keyboard input when using a mouse, I have taken steps to alleviate the issue for myself. I cannot fathom how a bunch of programmers whose purpose in this forum is to help others and to promote best practise in all things web, would not appreciate the viability of different user interactions and site navigation, but it is not for me to denigrate other users. I will leave that to other forum members who post negative comments or downvote simply because they do not agree with the post. I will no longer be requesting this feature, I have implemented an addon in the browser that gives me a RTT button. Although I enjoy coming to SO, and have been fortunate enough to post for some other users, I have no love for this pettiness or childish downvoting. Feel free to down vote this, but remember different people use things in different ways, and each way is as valid as each other. So, Just Do It - you win... I acquiesce to the lesser practise in order to not promote good site navigation and tolerance for all users use-cases. And really guys it is only a single link that could be added to the site / template in a heartbeat. But I bow to the superior knowledge of the forum and will not pursue this foolishness any longer.

Comment: You're mistaken, this was never about winning or losing an argument. It's just like @codygray said: *"There is a resistance to adding undesired junk to the page. What you see as a useful feature, others see as garbage taking up space on the screen, completely redundant with several other more normal and more useful methods of achieving the same goal"* I really couldn't have said it better.

Comment: I could say it like this "What you see as a useless feature or as garbage taking up space on the screen, completely redundant with several other more normal and more useful methods of achieving the same goal, I see as a valid and useful feature that would enhance my SO experience without resorting to using less familiar and less useful methods of achieving the same goal" , See what I did there - any argument that revolves around users saying "no" cos they don't like the idea can be negated by other users saying "yes" cos they do like the idea. Anyway I have flagged this to be deleted. You win.

Comment: Well guess what? The **community** disagrees, so stop thinking I have something personal against you.

Comment: I don't think that... oh wait you called me lazy, with no provocation and in response to a perfectly simple request. Choose your words more carefully in the future - words have consequences - even in an online forum.  And just because several vocal forum members disagree doesn't mean the forum disagrees, just that the members who are vocal and have the same mindset as you have spoken. These are probably the same users who shot down this request the other times it was raised - meaning that there are some users who feel the same way I do, so stop thinking you are speaking for the community.

Comment: I did choose my words, I could've called you anything I want, but instead I chose to use a pg-13 word, and I really couldn't care less about your "words have consequences"  threat. This request has been declined so many times so you should've known what the outcome of asking for it for the nth time would be. And yes I spoke for the community, for the community that actually cares about this site and visits meta, because those downvotes aren't all mine. Neither the close votes, much less the upvotes on my comment.

Comment: sorry - wasn't a threat - meant only that your insult made me think you have something personal against me and if this request has been asked for so many time (and then declined) then guess what genius, irrespective of the number of downvotes and declines, it means that there is a portion of this forum's user who want it. So therefore you do not speak for the entire community. and what, 8 downvotes out of thousands of members. Get real, just because a few people downvote me and upvote you does not mean anything. But I am done with this - I will submit no further posts on this subject.